# Is there any method to let Windows think I'm always connected to Internet?

Tags: windows, network-programming, captiveportal

According to [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/new-windows-10-bug-hits-home-working-outlook-o365-teams-cant-access-internet/), since Windows 10 2004 Update KB4535996, A lot of users get disconnected notice even if they connected and browsers works properly.

This blocks me from using a lot applications, Is there any method like:

- Globally Hook Windows NCSI(Network Connection Service Indicator) related API
- Change Registry to a always-connected site, like point some site to `127.0.0.1` and hijack `msftconnecttest.com` to this local IP
- Others you might know

to let windows think I'm **always connected to Internet** unless I disconnected physically?

Thank you.

PS. Related Registry Configurations are here: [image: Realted Windows Registry]

Comment: According to the link this was planned to be fixed in early April and available in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx).

Comment: In fact, It is no fixed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Someone invented this thing to bypass this, check it out here:

https://github.com/dantmnf/NCSIOverride

Comment: By the way, if you still have this problem after Aug, you should check your router configuration, set router to assign `DHCP-Options=6,<A DNS IP>`  will fix this issue for some usres.